# How do I pass a variable as a method to a Perl hash reference?

Tags: json, perl, reference

First of all, please correct my language in the title and body as regards what I'm calling the various Perl language constructs!

I'm having trouble passing a variable to a hash reference. Specifically, I'm using the JSON module to decode some JSON data and then access specific parts of that data.

Here is a sample of my JSON data:

```
[
 {
  label:"Blah",
  data:[
     [ 2112, 1 ]
  ]
 }
]
```

Now here is my Perl code:

```
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;
my $json = "*JSON data above*";
my $decoded_json = decode_json($json);

# This works, prints out '2112':
print( Dumper( $decoded_json->[0]{'data'}[0][0] ));

# What I'd like to do:
$datapath = "[0]{'data'}[0][0]";
print( Dumper( $decoded_json->$datapath ));
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You could use `eval` to do something like this, but that would be a really ugly thing to do.  Why are you encoding the 'coordinates' of the data in a string?  If it's arriving in a string, you might consider using a regexp to pull it out, especially if you need to validate it.

Comment: Thanks @JoeZ. The data is arriving in a JSON formatted string (from a web request). I don't need to validate it, I already know what the 'coordinates' are. However, I'm trying to generalize my script because I have different `$datapath` cases.

PS> It's amusing how reviled the `eval` function is. So far, I've gotten 'ugly', 'frowned upon' and 'problematic'! Ironically, it (seems to) work so well for my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't generally possible, but there are workarounds:

1. do a string-`eval`:

   ```
   my $val = do {
     local $@;
     my $val = eval "\$decoded_json->$datapath";
     die $@ if $@;
     $val;
   };
   ```

   Of course, using `eval` in this way is frowned upon.
2. Define a function that walks a data structure:

   ```
   sub walk {
     my $data = shift;
     while (@_) {
       my $index = shift;
       if (ref $data eq 'HASH') {
         $data = $data->{$index};
       } elsif (ref $data eq 'ARRAY') {
         $data = $data->[$index];
       } else {
         die qq(Wanted to use index "$index", but "$data" is neither hash nor array);
       }
     }
     return $data;
   }

   my $val = walk($decoded_json, 0, 'data', 0, 0);
   ```

   Of course, this would fail with overloaded objects.

Answer (score 3):

While it is possible to do that using eval, there are problems with that approach.

I suspect this is a better answer for your underlying problem:

```
use Data::Diver;
my @datapath = ( 0, 'data', 0, 0 );
print( Dumper( Data::Diver::Dive($decoded_json, @datapath) ));
```